# How to limit the drag range of angular material CDK drag and drop elements on a certain axis?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am making a To Do list, and I hope to expand the menu such as delete and edit functions by sliding to the left of each to do item.
But the question is how do I limit the drag range of each to do item?
In addition, I implemented this function by covering the 'mat-list-option' element on the button. When the mat-list-option is dragged away, the button underneath does not seem to get the mouse focus.

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far.